# Simulate 5g of acceleration on a test specimen

Tags: mechanical-engineering, solid-mechanics, product-testing

I am trying to simulate 5g of acceleration on a ventilation duct as it will utltimately be installed on a ship and I need to make sure it can withstand the platform movements which I estimated, with a bit of extra security margin, to be up to 5g.

I was thinking of dropping it from a certain height to simulate the acceleration as it hits the ground similarely to a drop test machine, unfortunately I don't have that type of equipment. Do you think it's a good way to test it ? if yes, how could I go about estimating the height I need to drop it from (knowing the test specimen is about 2kg) ?

I might be thinking of the problem in the wrong way so please correct me if it's the case.

Kind regards, Max

Comment: If you're doing a test to see if it can survive, you can relax the requirement of the test apparatus, and rather than $a=5g$, say you want $a>=5g$. So unless your safety margin on the design is trying to cut it close, a drop test would probably do. An swiging-pendulum impact device might be easier to work with, for generating an acceleration impulse. Either way, strap an accelerometer to the test specimen's mounting members to determine g load in practice. Alternatively, a pretty ordinary centrifuge should give you 5g without any guesswork, but if it's an HVAC duct, it would be big ish

Comment: PS - sounds like you're doing experiment (specifically, design verification test), and not simulation

Comment: "*If yes, how could I go about estimating the height I need to drop it from (knowing the test specimen is about 2kg)?*" Ehm, didn't Galileo Galilei demonstrate that the acceleration due to gravity was independent of mass - about 400 years ago - by dropping objects from the tower of Pisa?!

Comment: @Transistor - I think OP is asking about the impact, when the object decelerates upon hitting the ground - so the height is really a proxy for the impact speed

Comment: @PeteW, but how is the mass relevant? Am I missing something?

Comment: @Transistor - Oh true. It isn't. Misunderstood the point of your comment. The somewhat unpredictable part anyway is figuring out how short & sharp the impact is.